# HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler is null in Context_PreRequestHandlerExecute (IIS integrated mode)

Tags: iis-7, httphandler, integrated-pipeline-mode, wildcard-mapping

Helo community,

I migrate my application to the IIS integrated mode. (IIS 7.5)

I'm using the IIS wildcard mapping, so every request is processing through my application.

In the classic mode I get for each unhandled request a System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler, but in integrated mode there both (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler / HttpContext.Current.Handler) null.

Can I set a default handler for all unhandled requests?

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 2):

This helped me out:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/05/26/how-extensionless-urls-are-handled-by-asp-net-v4.aspx